# Weird amount of whitespace with People Reached stats

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, profile-page

As you can see, the whitespace between the text "people reached" and the rest of my other stats within the same box (i.e helpful flags, approved/applied edits, votes casted) looks to be not too much or too little:

[image]

But if we start visiting other people, the whitespace gets a bit extreme:

[Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post?tab=topactivity):

[image]

[Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=topactivity):

[image]

No, it's not a bug because I have the right whitespace. Other profiles have the correct amount of whitespace as well.

[Mari-Lou A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/223820/mari-lou-a?tab=topactivity):

[image]

Did anyone say that Shog9 and Tim Post both have more rep and impact than me and thus have the whitespace (like there's a threshold before the CSS gets weird)? Well, the below user doesn't:

[Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=topactivity)

[image]

So, can we have the whitespace fixed (normal) for *all profiles*?

Comment: The extra whitespace displaying when _track a tag badge_ and trimmed when _track new privilege_. This was a recent design change for the [Activity tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351378/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No bug here. The "posts edited", "helpful flags", and "votes cast" are aligned to the bottom, and the total height of that box match the height of the other two boxes in the same line, which are "reputation" and "badges".

As mentioned in [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298476/152859), when a user choose to track a tag badge, the design is different, and there is extra line so the "reputation"  box gets higher, forcing the other two boxes to be this height as well.

Let's put them side by side to see it more clearly:

> [image]

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

There was a new design change rolled out all over Stack Exchange sites for the [Activity tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351378/), to fix few alignment issues in the activty tab.

The extra whitespace are displaying when you are select **Track a tag badge instead** and those whitespaces are trimmed when you are select **Track my next privilege** options.

So IMO this is not [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: But I'm tracking both...

Comment: It's not about what you track, but what the user whose profile you view is tracking. @AnthonyPham.